# Including group_by in Custom Function R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, dplyr

I have a custom function that creates new rows, where it copies the data from row one and adds rows equal to a number in a specific column. Right now, the function works well if there is only one data entry per id. What I need is for the function to work when the data has multiple rows for one id.

My data includes id which is the persons id; Stage which is the stage the person is in; Start/ End which is the Start and End date; MonthDiff which is the difference between the start and end date, and a Censor which is equal to 0 or 1.

I need the function to be grouped by Stage and to copy rows down equal to the month diff in that stage and then restart.

What I have so far:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c('A','A','A'),
           Stage=c(1,2,3),
           Start=c(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2019-01-01')),
           End=c(as.Date('2015-12-31'),as.Date('2018-12-31'),as.Date('2020-02-01')),
           MonthDiff=c(23,35,13),
           Censor=c(0,0,1))

PLPP <- function(data, id,Stage, period, event) 
{stopifnot(is.matrix(data) || is.data.frame(data))
 stopifnot(c(id, period, event) %in% c(colnames(data), 1:ncol(data)))

 if (any(is.na(data[, c(id, period, event)]))) {
stop("PLPP cannot currently handle missing data in the id, period, or event variables")
}
       period = {
       index <- rep(1:nrow(data), data[, period])
       idmax<-cumsum(data[, period])
       reve <- !data[, event]
       dat <- data[index, ]
       dat[, period] <- ave(dat[, period], dat[, id], FUN = seq_along)
       dat[, event] <- 0
       dat[idmax, event] <- reve}


rownames(dat) <- NULL
 return(dat)
}

tpp<-PLPP(df,id='id',Stage = 'Stage',period = 'MonthDiff',event = 'Censor')

 test<-df%>%group_by(Stage)%>%do(tpp)
```

My problem with the current code is that the group_by statement isn't restarting at the new Stage.

Some references I've tried: [how to use group_by in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983225/how-to-use-group-by-in-a-function-in-r) ;
[Using dplyr group_by in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659943/using-dplyr-group-by-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, the variable `tpp` is a data frame, so it doesn't make much sense to pass it to `do` as if it were a function. You need to ensure `tpp` is a function that takes a data frame as an argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tpp <- function(df)
{
  PLPP(df, id='id', Stage = 'Stage', period = 'MonthDiff', event = 'Censor')
}
```

Within the `PLPP` function itself, your `period = {` section doesn't seem to like dealing with assignations to columns within you grouped tibble. It works as expected if you explicitly convert to a data.frame before this section:

```r
PLPP <- function(data, id,Stage, period, event)
{
  stopifnot(is.matrix(data) || is.data.frame(data))
  stopifnot(c(id, period, event) %in% c(colnames(data), 1:ncol(data)))

  if (any(is.na(data[, c(id, period, event)])))
  {
     stop("PLPP cannot currently handle missing data in the id, ",
          "period, or event variables")
  }

  data <- as.data.frame(data)

  period = {
    index <- rep(1:nrow(data), data[, period])
    idmax <- cumsum(data[, period])
    reve  <- !data[, event]
    dat   <- data[index, ]
    dat[, period] <- ave(dat[, period], dat[, id], FUN = seq_along)
    dat[, event]  <- 0
    dat[idmax, event] <- reve
  }

 rownames(dat) <- NULL
 return(dat)
}
```

So now you can do:

```
test <- df %>% group_by(Stage) %>% do(tpp(.))
```

And you get

```
test
#> # A tibble: 71 x 6
#> # Groups:   Stage [3]
#>    id    Stage Start      End        MonthDiff Censor
#>    <fct> <dbl> <date>     <date>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         1      0
#>  2 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         2      0
#>  3 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         3      0
#>  4 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         4      0
#>  5 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         5      0
#>  6 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         6      0
#>  7 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         7      0
#>  8 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         8      0
#>  9 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31         9      0
#> 10 A         1 2014-01-01 2015-12-31        10      0
#> # ... with 61 more rows
```

And it has the appropriate numbering per Stage:

```
test$MonthDiff
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23  1  2  3  4  5
#> [29]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
#> [57] 34 35  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```